# Advanced cURL and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl

I made a similar question few hours ago, but I think I asked a wrong question there. This is more exact one.

im using cURL on PHP and i want to use a site, but everytime i change my site, the browser posts a value **x** to server, and if you dont, you can't go to the site.

you can see that the x value changes all the time from the picture, its a FireFox Live HTTP headers addon, it shows what pages i visit with browser

[image: From FF live HTTP headers]

i looked the source code and found out what is the x value, and it comes from javascript. can i get the value with cURL or some other way from the server?

```
date = new Date();
    ms = (date.getHours() * 24 * 60 * 1000) + (date.getMinutes() * 60 * 1000) + (date.getSeconds() * 1000) + date.getMilliseconds();
```

**so the main problem is that the x value changes all the time and it has to be exactly "right" value , even milliseconds must be correct. i tried finding the value myself with javascript and then putting it to php, but still does not work**

Comment: Can you add your code and so we can see what you mean?

Comment: well lets say my page is www.google.com , i want to go to www.google.com/test.php .. when i press on the link the browser posts a value "x" to browser automatically as you can see from my picture right? , i think they made their site that way, but when i am using curl, then when i am using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/test.php?x=VALUE')` , so this posts the x for me.do you understand what i mean, i know its very fuzzy, but i try to explain

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple, you mixed between `$_POST` and `$_GET`

Check your PHP make sure is refer/using `$_GET['x']`

Comment: well lets say my page is www.google.com , i want to go to www.google.com/test.php .. when i press on the link the browser posts a value "x" to browser automatically as you can see from my picture right? , i think they made their site that way, but when i am using curl, then when i am using `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com/test.php?x=VALUE')` , so this posts the x for me. why would i need to use GET, do you understand what i mean, i know its very fuzzy, but i try to explain

Comment: You are doing a POST request instead of GET request, is up to the targeted script to response, if the script is using $_POST['x'], how do you expect it can work?

Comment: cause it has worked before on the site, but now they added the `x` variable and i just need to get the right value for it

Answer (score 0):

All that javascript is doing is calculating the current time in milliseconds on the client and sending it to the server. You can calculate such a time in php trivially with `$ms = time() * 1000;`

Comment: okay, but why I am getting different result then? my code and output [PICTURE](http://char.planet.ee/php/why.png)

Comment: Ok, well, read your JS code sample wrong. It's only returning the milliseconds since midnight of the current day. In PHP that would be `$ms = floor(((date('H') * 24*60*60) + (date('i') * 24*60) + date('s')) * 1000 + (date('u') / 1000));`